# Find $\{a_n\}$ such that ${a_n}^c > k \cdot e^{a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

- Given $c>0$ can we find $\{a_n\} > 0$, $N_0$,  such that

$$(a_n)^c > k e^{a_n} \quad \forall n>N_0, k>0$$.

- what if $\{a_n\} > 0$ is relaxed?

I was required to show $f(x)^c \in O(e^{f(x)})$ for $f(x)$ monotonic, which I could do using Taylor expansion of $e^x$, but I didn't use the monotonicity condition. So I was wondering if there are sequences for which this breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise depends is true even if $f(x)$ is not monotonic, it's enought to assume that $f(x)>0\, \forall x$ (within the definition area). This assumption should be given, since $c$ doens't have to be a natural number.

For the exercise, it is enough to show that $\dfrac{e^{f(x)}}{f(x)^c}\geq M$ for some $M>0$.

For a sketch proof, one can use the Taylor expansion to see that $\dfrac{e^{f(x)}}{f(x)^c}$ is equal to $k_1 f(x)^{d_1} + k_2 f(x)^{d_2}$ plus many more summands bigger than $0$, where $-1\leq d_1<0$ and $0<d_2\leq 1$, and $k_1, \, k_2 >0$. If $f(x)$ tends to $0$ or infinity, one of those two summands goes to infinity. For in between, it is easy to prove that the function is bounded from below. (Remark for everyone reading that: This is only a raw sketch of the proof)

Is that possibly similar to the way you approached?

This does also answer the question about the sequences: It doesn't exist.

Comment: "you need f(x) to be monotonically increasing" - Can you elaborate why? Also, I have updated the question according to your suggestion. Also, continuity of f(x) is not guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, there's a big update on the answer since I had only one very typical way of using taylor expansion in my mind, which would require $f(x)$ going to infinity. (Which is not given here) I've posted a way using Taylor expansion for the proof that $f(x)^c \in O(e^{f(x)})$.

Comment: Could you explain me what you mean with "relaxed"? I've never seen the word in such a context and haven't found anything in the internet.

Comment: There is still an issue with the question: What I assume you want to ask about a sequence where $(a_n)^c$ gets arbitrarily much bigger that $e^{a_n}$. Then,you need to set $k$ before $N_0$: "Given $c>0$, can we find $\{ a_n\} >0$, such that $\forall k>0$, we find $N_0=N_0(k)$ with $(a_n)^c > ke^{a_n}\, \forall n>N_0$.

Comment: by "relaxed" i mean, if the condition is removed. Find $\{a_n\}$ such that $\frac{(a_n)^c}{ e^{a_n}} \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: "...where $(a_n)^c$ gets arbitrarily much bigger than $e^{a_n}$ ..." precisely. Are there such sequences even if $a_n$ can be negative?

Comment: For $a_n$ bigger than $0$, this doesn't exist, as shown above, as you did in the exercise. If $a_n$ is negative, we need $c$ to be a natural number. If $c=2$ and $    a_n= -n$, the fraction goes to infinity.